# Is it possible to perform a XSS attack using jQuery's .attr("href", value) method for <a> tags?

Tags: jquery, html, xss

Given is the following html fragment, which is statically typed in an html file:

```
<a id="link001" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Please consider, that the attribute value of `href` is quoted. Is it possible to perform a XSS attack when the attacker can provide an arbitrary value for the variable `unsafe_string` in the following context:

```
$('#link001').attr("href", unsafe_string);
```

My question is: Is it possible to inject and execute malicious code? The attacker has only control of `unsafe_string` and nothing else. The attacker can assume that the victim will finally click the link.

The case, that a user can get forwarded to some malicious website by clicking the link should get neglected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's unsafe, one can just prepend `javascript:` to the malicious code:

```js
$('#link001').attr("href", "javascript:alert('evil')");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link001" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Comment: Is there a safe possibility to prevent JS execution for this scenario? Wrapping `unsafe_string` into the function `encodeURI()` will not help. Checking for specific character sequences is very error-prone, as different encodings can be applied. Checking that the url starts with `http` or `https` could be one idea, but it is not that suitable if also relative links should be allowed.

Comment: My initial thought would be to make sure the string just doesn't start with `javascript:` (case insensitive); once that's taken care of, do you know of any other possible exploitation paths?

Comment: Prepending e.g. control characters and spaces will also allow running javascript: `$('#link001').attr("href", "\n\b\r\t  jAvAsCrIpT:alert('evil')");` Maybe it is better to force the user to provide absolute urls, as every relative url can be written as absolute url and follow the whitelist approach, requiring that the given string exactly starts with `http` (or `http://`) or `https` (or `https://`).

Comment: Furthermore, maybe there still exist some other script languages which could be executed in some cases (in some browsers), like for example: `$('#link001').attr("href", "vbscript:msgbox('XSS')");` or `$('#link001').attr("href", "livescript:[code]");`